# Change default idseparator in .Net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-controls

Okay,
Here`s the scenario:

We portted a legacy web project from .Net 1.1 to .Net 3.5, and most things work the way it was intended.

But we have a weird situation,
Even tho the idseparator for rendering names in webcontrols from asp.net was changed from ":" to "$" in .Net 2.0, our local development machine still renders Asp.Net Controls using ":" as an idseparator for names.

But when we deployed our web project to one of our test servers, those same asp.net controls was being rendered using a "$" as idseparator for names.

So,

Question 1:
why is it behaving this way only in our test servers and not on our local machines?

Question 2:
Even if we manage to "fix" our local development machine to render the correct default character separator("$"), it would break some legacy js code, which assumes asp.net controls renders names using ":" separator.
Could we just change the default character separator back to a colon(":") in our test servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick review of how UniqueID is generated with .NET Reflector shows that you can get ":" instead of "$" by using `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />` in Web.Config.

However it can introduce another issues.

Details:

There's a protected  property `Control.IdSeparator` used intenally to get separator character during UniqueId generation:

```
protected char IdSeparator
{
  [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
  get
  {
    if (this.Page != null)
    {
      return this.Page.IdSeparator;
    }
    return this.IdSeparatorFromConfig;
  }
}
```

Where `IdSeparatorFromConfig` is

```
internal char IdSeparatorFromConfig
{
  get
  {
    if (!this.EnableLegacyRendering)
    {
      return '$';
    }
    return ':';
  }
}
```

and `EnableLegacyFromConfig` is

```
internal bool EnableLegacyRendering
{
    get
    {
        System.Web.UI.Page page = this.Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            return (page.XhtmlConformanceMode == XhtmlConformanceMode.Legacy);
        }
        return ((!this.DesignMode && (this.Adapter == null)) && (this.GetXhtmlConformanceSection().Mode == XhtmlConformanceMode.Legacy));
    }
}
```